# How to group and average fields by criteria in ms access

Tags: database, ms-access

I need to figure out a way to display a list of averages by resource in MS Access. For simplicity's sake, let's say the data consists of a list of projects, each of which have a numerical status indicator (e.g. % complete). Each of these projects has been assigned a resource. What I need to do is be able to average the status indicators together **by resource**. I then need to display that list of averages by resource.

For example, let's say that there are two resources - A and B - and four projects. The data is something like this:

```
ProjectID | ResourceAssigned | Project Status

 - 1      |         A        |     50% 
 - 2      |         B        |     30% 
 - 3      |         A        |     70% 
 - 4      |         B        |     50%
```

Assuming equal weighting, Resource A would have a "status" of 60% (avg of 70% and 50%), and Resource B will have a "status" of 40% (avg of 30% and 50%). How can I get Access to calculate  and display this for me (keeping in mind that additional Resources will be added to the system as well)?

Answer (score 3):

Please try:

```
SELECT  ResourceAssigned, AVG([Project Status]) AS AvgOfProjectStatus
GROUP BY ResourceAssigned
```

Comment: Thanks - this is the right track, and I think I figured out what I needed. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem :) I'm glad I could help at least a little.